# SQL Server 2008 R2 Instance Rename Broke Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, rename

Renamed a production instance during a move to virtual. The aftermath was that our replication broke. The replication subscriber and publisher both were removed and the jobs disabled - but every day the publisher and distributor try to still read the logs.

Has anyone experienced this before? Can you point me in the direction of what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: This probably belongs at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename an instance that is involved in replication.  It will break replication.  You must drop and recreate replication after a rename.

Comment: Tried that - it drops pieces, but not the entire replication.

Comment: Tried what?  What drops pieces?

Comment: We tried to drop the replication and recreate it after the rename - It dropped the subscriber and publication but the publisher and distributor still exist and even with the jobs disabled, still tries to read the logs which throws errors.

Comment: Interesting, you must not have dropped it correctly.  To completely remove replication you will need to delete the publication, delete the subscriptions, and disable publishing and distribution.  Have a look here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152757.aspx